# How could I infuse elements with other elements in an xml using Minidom?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm using minidom with Python 3.5

The original xml data looks like this: 
(# of Beat and EditData_Score node/tags are fixed (in this case 3 each).

```
<EditData_Score>
<EditDataType>BEAT_SCORE</EditDataType>
<Spot>20</Spot>
<Time>7</Time>
<Type>X</Type>
<Beat>
<EditDataType>BEAT_MARK</EditDataType>
<Spot>26</Spot>
<BeatLength>4.84472036</BeatLength>
</Beat>
</EditData_Score>
<EditData_Score>
<EditDataType>BEAT_SCORE</EditDataType>
<Spot>36</Spot>
<Time>10</Time>
<Type>X</Type>
<Beat>
<EditDataType>BEAT_MARK</EditDataType>
<Spot>48</Spot>
<BeatLength>4.84472036</BeatLength>
</Beat>
</EditData_Score>
```

As you can see, Beat elements are nested in EditData_Score elements. 
And the Spot node's value is always increasing. I want to consolidate EditData_Score elements, add some minor alterations then put and redistribute the Beats within them such that the EditData_Score encapsulates all specified beats:

```
<EditData_Score>
<EditDataType>BEAT_SCORE</EditDataType>
<Spot>20</Spot>
<Time>17</Time>
<Type>X</Type>
<Beat>
<EditDataType>BEAT_MARK</EditDataType>
<Spot>26</Spot>
<BeatLength>4.84472036</BeatLength>
</Beat>
<Beat>
<EditDataType>BEAT_MARK</EditDataType>
<Spot>48</Spot>
<BeatLength>4.84472036</BeatLength>
</Beat>
</EditData_Score>
```

I figured I could parse the xml once and:

- add all the Beats I want to group to a list
- add all the EditDataScores I want to keep to a list

Parse it again and:

- Delete/Remove/Unset? all the old Beats and EditDataScores
- Barf out the Beat Groups in the appropriate EditDataScore

Comment: So basically you want only 1 `EditData_Score` that holds all the data? Can you add a link to the file?

Comment: Hello, Padraic.  Thank you for the reply.  Not necessarily just 1.  Before Editing there could be anywhere from 4 to 8.  I need there to be exactly 4 EditData_Score-s  in the resultant xml.   I'll get on the link.

Comment: I got the files but won't get a chance until this evening to have a proper look, are you open to using  lxml or even xml.etree?

Comment: You can take it down now if you like as I have the files downloaded

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!  No problem at all, I have plenty of time, no rush whatsoever.  I'm totally open to using lxml or etree.  I've actually tried using them a couple times before, but the usage tutorials I've found for them resulted in lots of compile errors (could have something to do with them being geared towards python 2.7).  I'm a newb with python and xml in general.  For some reason I got the best luck with minidom so I decided to stick with it.

Comment: lxml is by far the best so it is definitely worth the time to get it working, I will give you a ping when I get something throw together.

Comment: Sorry, there's something I forgot to mention. Most (about half) of the data in the xml won't be modified.  I need to retain it and then modify specific parts/elements based on simple, yet specific, conditions.  In the interim --starting tomorrow-- I'll look into converting the current script to lxml.

Comment: You mean some EditData_Scores won't be modified?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. All EditData_Scores will be modified, but to what degree depends on certain conditions.  In the data file I supplied, the "data" I was referring to that would not be modified would be lines 1 to 2008.   I use the EVENT elements to check how many EditData_Scores there are in each "round".  If it's just 1 in a round, I will only change the value of its <name> node.  If there are 2 in a round then I need to make lots of changes, namely nest Rythm_Marks into it.

Comment: Though I was hoping switching to lxml would require I just change function calls, it seems I'm going to have to rewrite the script altogether. Makes me still hope I could do it with minidom.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry to bump this.  Do you think you can still help?  Thanks in advance!