# How to delete a single opening or closing tag in an XML using minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432161/how-would-i-combine-nested-elements-in-an-xml-using-minidom) thread last week, but haven't got any replies so maybe it was too poorly worded and therefore incomprehensible.

Using python 3.5 and its default minidom, I would like to know if it's possible to turn this:

```
<EditData_Score>
<EditDataType>BEAT_SCORE</EditDataType>
<Beat>
<EditDataType>BEAT_MARK</EditDataType>
</Beat>
</EditData_Score>
```

into this (no opening tag for parent element):

```
<EditDataType>BEAT_SCORE</EditDataType>
<Beat>
<EditDataType>BEAT_MARK</EditDataType>
</Beat>
</EditData_Score>
```

and or this (no closing tag for parent element):

```
<EditData_Score>
<EditDataType>BEAT_SCORE</EditDataType>
<Beat>
<EditDataType>BEAT_MARK</EditDataType>
</Beat>
```

I'd think if I knew the line number I could just delete it that way, but from what I've researched there isn't a clean way to do it in minidom.

Thanks!

Comment: by 'parent element' do you mean 'root element'?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, TheLazyScripter. I apologize for my lack of xml lingo.  

Referencing [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp) xml tree structure I'd think this element line is the root since 98% of the xml elements are nested within it: 

<EditXmlData xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">;

I basically want to remove an opening or closing tag (not both) from a child element that contains other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When XML data is loaded into a DOM representation, the concept of opening/closing tags does not exist.  The DOM knows about *elements* and their contents.  The existence of tags (opening and closing) has to do only with the serialized version of the DOM -- i.e. they are a necessary part of the serialized encoding but NOT part of the semantics of the document.

A serialized representation with multiple top-level tags, or missing a start or end tag, is not a valid representation of an XML document and cannot be loaded into a DOM (or created programmatically in a DOM) instance.

If you MUST do this you will have to post-process the output using either an output filter or a separate program, or write a custom serializer.

Comment: Jim Garrison, thank you very much for the concise explanation.  Thanks to it I have a better understanding of how I am to use it.  I'm not entirely sure if I must delete opening/closing tags.  I'm only sure I must manipulate element contents.